# Read a specific column from a csv file in C#

Tags: c#, csv

I have a simple 3 column csv file and i need to exctract only the information from the first column. I was thinking of regular expressions, but i am hoping there is an easier more efficient approach.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Do the column values vary in length?

Comment: Yes. The values in the first column are unique ID's

Comment: The second sentence does not really imply varying length, as a unique ID could be a GUID which is always the same size.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using this [A Fast CSV Reader](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/CsvReader.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`TextFieldParser`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.textfieldparser.aspx) class that is in the `Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO` namespace.

It will parse the file and the resulting object can be queried, so you will be able to get the values in the first column.

Answer (score 0):

You can read line by line and use the split method to split the line you have read into colums and keep the column you want. [Here](http://www.dotnetperls.com/string-split) is a simple example on how to use the split method.

Comment: Note that simply splitting has problems with parsing quoted fields in CSV.

Answer (score 0):

I'd go like this : load the csv file to a datatable and then handle it however i want, by column, or by row. 
here's [a link](http://www.akamarketing.com/blog/256-csv-datatable.html) with some directions

Answer (score 0):

As stated in dozens of questions before there are two candidates for easy reading of .csv files:

- [FileHelpers](http://filehelpers.sourceforge.net/)
- [Fast CSV Reader](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/CsvReader.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to extract that data into a class object, [CsvHelper](http://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/) (a library I maintain) is a good option.

```
var csv = new CsvHelper( File.OpenRead( "file.csv" ) );
var myCustomObjects = csv.Reader.GetRecords<MyCustomObject>();
```